# Meteor Collection Transform: is it done on the server or on the client? or it depends

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to use transform to make a "virtual field" out of a collection. However, the new field I'm adding (within the transform function) is adding quite a bit of data to the returned document.

This is fine if the transform is taking place inside the client. If it is done on server-side, then there will be bandwidth concerns.

So I'm wondering if the transform is done on the server, or on the client, or it depends on how I find/fetch the document?

Comment: Instead of creating the new field in the transform function, can't you add a function to the document that will return the same value? In this way, you maybe get around the problem you (think you) have?

Comment: Oh yes. But I was more interested in knowing if the transformed doc actually gets passed from server to client. Just a bit technicality.

Comment: Just note that the transform function is applied after you `fetch()` the document (or equivalent). `find()` will return the cursor. After fetching results, the function is applied.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It's possible to do a transform on the server.

You can have a transform on the client like this:

```
return YourCollection.find({}, {transform: function (doc) {
   doc.test = true;
   return true;
}});
```

Meteor ignores `transform` on queries that are published (from within `Meteor.publish`). The client sees the document as if the transform didn't exist.

If you would like to use transforms on the server you can do this:

```
YourCollection = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name"); 

Meteor.publish("yourRecordSet", function() {

  //Transform function
  var transform = function(doc) {
    doc.date = new Date();
    return doc;
  }

  var self = this;

  var observer = YourCollection.find().observe({
      added: function (document) {
      self.added('collection_name', document._id, transform(document));
    },
    changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
      self.changed('collection_name', newDocument._id, transform(newDocument));
    },
    removed: function (oldDocument) {
      self.removed('collection_name', oldDocument._id);
    }
  });

  self.onStop(function () {
    observer.stop();
  });

  self.ready();

});
```

Comment: Great, thanks for taking `Meteor.publish` into consideration as well. You answered exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @Akshat you said: "The transformed collection will not be sent to the client", so can I conclude that it is not possible to create "virtual fields" and keep clients unaware?

Comment: @Hamal000 you can use `this.added` to create entirely virtual documents with virtual fields, but you would have to manage the changes with `this.changed` yourself. The chat rooms example on the meteor docs shows this

Comment: That code sets up a new publication with the collection set to the same name as the target collection; without that extra observer being set up, server transforms still won't reach the client, and it would still be nice if [meteor issue 821](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/821) were fixed.

Comment: @DanDascalescu this isn't a 'new publish' you just use this instead of the publish you would use already. The transform given by the `transform` method reaches the client as the intention of the question. When you `return Collection.find` Meteor does this under the hood, I've just modified it to add a transform in.

Comment: Alright, if phrased that way, then yes, transforms on the server will reach the client. But hasn't this always worked in Meteor, if you set up your own `added`, `changed` and `removed`? The elegant solution would be to use [the documented transform function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection), and have the transformed documents be sent via DDP to the client, without the boilerplate code of setting up the observers. Agree?

Comment: Yes I agree, This code above is boilerplate if Meteor implements it it would be more helpful. I updated the answer because it said there was no way of doing it previously.

Answer (score 3):

You can add and use the following function:

```
Meteor.publishWithTransform = function(publicationName, cursorGetter , transform)
{
    transform = transform || function(o){return o;};
    Meteor.publish(publicationName, function ()
    {
        var cursor = cursorGetter.apply(this, arguments);
        var collectionName = cursor._cursorDescription.collectionName;

        var self = this;

        var observer = cursor.observe({
            added: function (document) {
                self.added(collectionName, document._id, transform(document));
            },
            changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
                self.changed(collectionName, newDocument._id, transform(newDocument));
            },
            removed: function (oldDocument) {
                self.removed(collectionName, oldDocument._id);
            }
        });

        self.onStop(function () {
            observer.stop();
        });

        self.ready();
    });
}
```

Usage (server side):

```
Meteor.publishWithTransform("publication-name", function () {
    aCollection.find({})
}, function (item)
{
    item.aField = "something";
    return item;
});
```

Drawback: if you save the published document you will save the added changes as well. Here the client has no clue the property "aField" has been added during the publication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform on both sides, when you specify a transform option to the collection or findOne,fetch,etc

> transform Function
>   An optional transformation function. Documents will be passed through this function before being returned from fetch or findOne, and before being passed to callbacks of observe, allow, and deny.

If you need to get raw document from a collection with transform option.

```
myCollection.findOne({},{transform:null})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add transform directly in the collection definition as well. Note: As mentioned above this runs the risk of storing extra data to your collection when updating.  For read only collections this isn't really an issue.

I am also expecting this to live in a shared lib folder or similar, both client and server see this definition.

```
var Assignment;

// Every record in this collection will now be an 
// instance of the Assignment class.
this.AssignmentsReport = new Mongo.Collection("assignments", {
  transform: function(doc) {
    return new Assignment(doc._id, doc.assignId, doc.masterId);
  }
});

// Creating a class instance to actually map the new object.
Assignment = (function() {
  function Assignment(_id, assignId, masterId) {
    var assign, ref;
    this._id = _id;
    this.assignId = assignId;
    this.masterId = masterId;
    this.assign = (ref = Assignments.find({
      _id: this.assignId
    }).fetch()) != null ? ref[0] : void 0;
  }

  return Assignment;

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also meteor Package that allows to add transforms on server side for publish https://atmospherejs.com/maximum/server-transform