# How to publish a view/transform of a collection in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have made a collection

```
var Words = new Meteor.Collection("words");
```

and published it:

```
Meteor.publish("words", function() {
    return Words.find();
});
```

so that I can access it on the client. Problem is, this collection is going to get very large and I just want to publish a transform of it. For example, let's say I want to publish a summary called "num words by length", which is an array of ints, where the index is the length of a word and the item is the number of words of that length. So

```
wordsByLength[5] = 12;
```

means that there are 12 words of length 5. In SQL terms, it's a simple GROUP BY/COUNT over the original data set. I'm trying to make a template on the client that will say something like

- You have N words of length X

for each length. My question boils down to "I have my data in form A, and I want to publish a transformed version, B".

Comment: Duplicate of [Meteor Collection Transform: is it done on the server or on the client? or it depends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093560/meteor-collection-transform-is-it-done-on-the-server-or-on-the-client-or-it-de)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE** You can transform a collection on the server like this:

```
Words = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name"); 

Meteor.publish("yourRecordSet", function() {

  //Transform function
  var transform = function(doc) {
    doc.date = new Date();
    return doc;
  }

  var self = this;

  var observer = Words.find().observe({
      added: function (document) {
      self.added('collection_name', document._id, transform(document));
    },
    changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
      self.changed('collection_name', oldDocument._id, transform(newDocument));
    },
    removed: function (oldDocument) {
      self.removed('collection_name', oldDocument._id);
    }
  });

  self.onStop(function () {
    observer.stop();
  });

  self.ready();

});
```

Comment: Thanks Akshat, I think Meteor Streams will fit the bill. What I really need is a general purpose message passing mechanism.

Comment: does this change any data in the database or does it only send the additional data to the client?

Comment: @pushplaybang It doesn't change your database just lets you customise what the client sees, you can even get data from somewhere else other than a database

Comment: Hi there, I think the transform function above needs to return doc not date.

Comment: Is that ok that the publish function has no return? It seems to publish nothing to the client for me

Comment: @Guig You're not publishing nothing, you're publishing the items in the custom observer. It is important *not* to return anything. Meteor takes what you return and does the same above for each collection.

Comment: @Akshat thanks, I stupidly didn't adapted the code correctly... from http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_added it's not 100% clear if this is only going to impact the current subscribing user or all the user who subscribed to the document (I'll guess the former, but I wanted to check that)

Comment: should `self.changed('collection_name', document._id, transform(newDocument));` be `self.changed('collection_name', oldDocument._id, transform(newDocument));` ?

Answer (score 1):

To wrap transformations mentioned in other answers, you could use the package I developed, [meteor-middleware](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-middleware). It provides a nice pluggable API for this. So instead of just providing a transform, you can stack them one on another. This allows for code reuse, permissions checks (like removing or aggregating fields based on permissions), etc. So you could create a class which allows you to aggregate documents in the way you want.

But for your particular case you might want to look into [MongoDB aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). If there is really a lot of words you probably do not want to transfer all of them from the MongoDB server to the Meteor server side. On the other hand, aggregation pipeline lacks the reactivity you might want to have. So that published documents change counts as words come in and go.

To address that you could use another package I developed, [PeerDB](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-peerdb). It allows you to specify triggers which would be reactively called as data changes, and stored in the database. Then you could simply use normal publishing to send counts to the client. The downside is that all users should be interested in the same collection. It works globally, not per user. But if you are interested in counts of words per whole collection, you could do something like (in CoffeesScript):

```
class WordCounts extends Document
  @Meta
    name: 'WordCounts'

class Words extends Document
  @Meta
    name: 'Words'
    triggers: =>
      countWords: @Trigger ['word'], (newDocument, oldDocument) ->
        # Document has been removed.
        if not newDocument._id
          WordCounts.update
            length: oldDocument.word.length
          ,
            $inc:
              count: -1
        # Document has been added.
        else if not oldDocument._id
          WordCounts.update
            length: newDocument.word.length
          ,
            $inc:
              count: 1
        # Word length has changed.
        else if newDocument.word.length isnt oldDocument.word.length
          WordCounts.update
            length: oldDocument.word.length
          ,
            $inc:
              count: -1
          WordCounts.update
            length: newDocument.word.length
          ,
            $inc:
              count: 1
```

And then you could simply publish `WordCounts` documents:

```
Meteor.publish 'counts', ->
  WordCounts.documents.find()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assemble the counts by going through each document in Words, ([cursor for each](http://docs.meteor.com/#foreach))

```
var countingCursor = Words.find({});
var wordCounts = {};

countingCursor.forEach(function (word) {
  wordCounts[word.length].count += 1;
  wordCounts[word.length].words = wordCounts[word.length].words || []
  wordCounts[word.length].words.push(word);
});
```

create a local collection,

```
var counts = new Meteor.Collection('local-counts-collection', {connection: null});
```

and insert your answers

```
var key, value;

for (key in wordCounts) {
  value = object[key];
  counts.insert({
    length: key,
    count: value.count,
    members: value.words
  });
}
```

Counts is now a collection, just not stored in Mongo.

Not tested!