# How to 'transform' data returned via a Meteor.publish?

Tags: meteor

Meteor Collections have a [transform](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) ability that allows behavior to be attached to the objects returned from mongo.

We want to have autopublish turned off so the client does not have access to the database collections, but we still want the transform functionality.

We are sending data to the client with a more explicit Meteor.publish/Meteor.subscribe or the RPC mechanism ( Meteor.call()/Meteor.methods() )

How can we have the Meteor client automatically apply a transform like it will when retrieving data directly with the Meteor.Collection methods?

Comment: Can't you just have the transformation function apply on the server so it is transformed within the method? Or you can manually transform the results of the method call.

Comment: If your methods are just basic database queries, it may be easier to explicitly allow only certain client queries with [`collection.allow()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) and [`collection.deny()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deny) rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Meteor 0.7.0.1) - meteor does allow behavior to be attached to the objects returned via the pub/sub.

This is from a pull request I submitted to the meteor project.

```
Todos = new Meteor.Collection('todos', {
// transform allows behavior to be attached to the objects returned via the pub/sub communication.
      transform : function(todo) {
          todo.update = function(change) {
             Meteor.call('Todos_update', this._id, change);
          },
          todo.remove = function() {
             Meteor.call('Todos_remove', this._id);
          }
         return todo;
     }
});
todosHandle = Meteor.subscribe('todos');
```

Any objects returned via the 'todos' topic will have the update() and the remove() function - which is exactly what I want: I now attach behavior to the returned data.

Answer (score 13):

While you can't directly use transforms, there is a way to transform the result of a database query before publishing it. This is what the "publish the current size of a collection" example describes [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish).

It took me a while to figure out a really simple application of that, so maybe my code will help you, too:

```js
Meteor.publish("publicationsWithHTML", function (data) {
    var self = this;
    Publications
        .find()
        .forEach(function(entry) {
            addSomeHTML(entry);  // this function changes the content of entry
            self.added("publications", entry._id, entry);
        });
    self.ready();
});
```

On the client you subscribe to this:

```js
Meteor.subscribe("publicationsWithHTML");
```

But your model still need to create a collection (on both sides) that is called 'publications':

```js
Publications = new Meteor.Collection('publications');
```

Mind you, this is not a very good example, as it doesn't maintain the reactivity. But I found the count example a bit confusing at first, so maybe you'll find it helpful.

Comment: This is a good point, and could be useful depending on the requirements (and the observe complexity). Another example I like is [this one](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/4iCcqw8vPCyCWmiuT) from [EventedMind](https://www.eventedmind.com/).

Comment: A important note: the collection does *not* need to be on the server. The self.added() shoud be self.added("publicationsWithHTML", .... ) (I have learned since I asked this question)

Comment: When you subscribe to this collection you won't be able to observe changes on the collection. For example if some client adds a doc to Publications collection other clients won't be able to see that new doc.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
let transformTodo = (fields) => {
  fields._pubType = 'todos';
  return fields;
};

Meteor.publish('todos', function() {
  let subHandle = Todos
    .find()
    .observeChanges({
      added: (id, fields) => {
        fields = transformTodo(fields);
        this.added('todos', id, fields);
      },
      changed: (id, fields) => {
        fields = transformTodo(fields);
        this.changed('todos', id, fields);
      },
      removed: (id) => {
        this.removed('todos', id);
      }
    });
  this.ready();
  this.onStop(() => {
    subHandle.stop();
  });
});
```

Comment: this helped me. i needed access to the cursor separately, so i separated out the find() call. i ended up with: let handle = cursor.observerChanges()...

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't apply transforms on the server to published collections. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343534/how-to-publish-a-view-transform-of-a-collection-in-meteor) question for more details. That leaves you with either transforming the data on the client, or using a meteor method. In a method, you can have the server do whatever you want to the data.

In one of my projects, we perform our most expensive query (it joins several collections, denormalizes the documents, and trims unnecessary fields) via a method call. It isn't reactive, but it greatly simplifies our code because all of the transformation happens on the server.

Comment: "transforming on the client" is exactly what we needed. ( see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Christian Fritz answer, with Reactive Solution using [peerlibrary:reactive-publish](https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/reactive-publi)

```
Meteor.publish("todos", function() {
  const self = this;
  return this.autorun(function(computation) {

    // Loop over each document in collection 

     todo.find().forEach(function(entry) {

    // Add function to transform / modify each document here

      self.added("todos", entry._id, entry);
    });
  });
});
```