# Add computed fields to Meteor.users in a publication

Tags: meteor

I am trying to publish a custom computed field `isFriend` in publication that returns a record from `Meteor.user`.

I tried various solutions but none of them seen to work:

- Transform from a publication does not work as described here ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344597/644081
- I tried the solution here [How can I add temp. fields to a Meteor publish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21127660/644081) .. buy doesn't work either ... see code below

Code:

```
Meteor.publish("viewProfile", function(id) {
  console.log("Finding the user: " + id);
  var self = this;
  Meteor.users
      .find({"_id": id})
      .forEach(function(entry) {
          entry.isFriend = true;  // this function changes the content of entry
          self.added("Meteor.users", entry._id, entry);
      });
    self.ready();
});
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to transform a document is to add a `transform` option to your [collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection). You can do this directly with the meteor API, or with a package like [collection-helpers](http://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers) (see the docs for more details).

However, sometimes you need to transform documents before they get published because only the server has the necessary information. A good example is a signed URL. In this case you can use an `observe` or an `observeChanges` to manipulate each object.

`observeChanges` is much more efficient but it can only operate on partial documents (e.g. if you wanted to transform a single field that already exists). In your example, you need to see the entire document in order to add the field, so you need an `observe`. Give the following a try:

```js
Meteor.publish('viewProfile', function(userId) {
  check(userId, String);

  // modify this as needed
  var transform = function(user) {
    user.isFriend = true;
    return user;
  };

  // only publish the fields you really need
  var fields = {username: 1, emails: 1, profile: 1};

  var self = this;

  var handle = Meteor.users.find(userId, {fields: fields}).observe({
    added: function (user) {
      self.added('users', user._id, transform(user));
    },

    changed: function (user) {
      self.changed('users', user._id, transform(user));
    },

    removed: function (user) {
      self.removed('users', user._id);
    }
  });

  this.ready();

  this.onStop(function() {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anybody else, I adapted David Weldon's answer to return a handle so that the client can test whether the subscription is ready. Something like this:

in publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish('viewProfile', function(userId) {
  check(userId, String);

  // modify this as needed
  var transform = function(user) {
    user.isFriend = true;
    return user;
  };

  // only publish the fields you really need
  var fields = {username: 1, emails: 1, profile: 1};

  var self = this;

  var handle = Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {fields: fields})

  const subsription = handle.observe({
    added: function (user) {
      self.added('users', user._id, transform(user));
    },

    changed: function (user) {
      self.changed('users', user._id, transform(user));
    },

    removed: function (user) {
      self.removed('users', user._id);
    }
  });

  this.ready();

  this.onStop(function() {
    subsription.stop();
  });

  return handle;
});
```

Now in the client you can do:

```
const handle = Meteor.subscribe('viewProfile', userId);

const isLoading = !handle.ready();
```