# How to add computed properties to a Meteor Collection

Tags: collections, meteor, aggregation-framework, reactive-programming, computation

I want to add some dynamically computed properties to a server side collection and then send this combined collection to the client.

Lets say I have a simple page where one could post questions and then attach answers to those.

There are two collections: `Questions` and `Answers`.
Each answer has a property `questionId`.

On the client side I would like to show a list of all questions, each with it's answer count. I don't want to send the `Answers` collection down the wire due to bandwidth considerations. Ideally I want the count to behave reactively.

- Question 1 (12 Answers)
- Question 2 (4 Answers)

My Solutions for this so far don't look very 'Meteorish' to me.

**First Solution** was to simply add an `answerCount` property to each question and then modify that property when an answer was added or deleted. However I don't like the duplicated information and it also does not work if the computation has some dynamic parameters that might change.

**Second Solution** was to use a method call for the server side computation:

```
Meteor.methods({
  numOfAnswers: function(questionId) {
    return Answers.find({questionId: questionId}).count();
  }
});
```

From the client side I would use a template helper like:

```
numOfAnswers: function(){
  return ReactiveMethod.call("numOfAnswers", this._id);
}
```

Even though this works fine, it causes a lot of method calls and it is not reactive at all.

Probably another solution could be to use MongoDB aggregations (maybe via meteorhacks:aggregate) but then again this is not reactive and maybe a bit overkill.

I ran into this problem a few times at different places. Do I miss something obvious here?

Comment: You may want to consider a complex publish function, see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895154/how-to-transform-data-returned-via-a-meteor-publish

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Turns out that a transform might be just what I need (as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343534/how-to-publish-a-view-transform-of-a-collection-in-meteor).