# Transforming DB Collections in Meteor.publish

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

Hopefully this question is not too long but I am trying to include as much details as possible in what I did..

I am trying to figure out how to implement logic in `Meteor.publish()` that takes data from the DB, changes all the values in a column and makes the updated collection available for client-side subscription.
Specifically, I have a table that stores messages between users and the recipient is identified by his userId. I would like to replace the userId with his actual phone number which should be available in the `Meteor.users` table.

When I looked it up online I saw suggestions to use `transform` but my understanding is that it's not reactive.. I then learned about `map` but discovered that it returns an array which breaks the `Meteor.publish()` method. Finally I found something that uses `forEach` and `self.added()` and `self.ready()` so my code currently looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish("myMessages", function () {
    var self = this;
    Messages.find({ 
        $or: [
            { senderId: this.userId },
            { recipientId: this.userId }
        ]
    }).forEach(function(m) {
        m.recipientId = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: m.recipientId }).username;
        console.log("adding msg to collection:");
        console.log(m);
        self.added("Messages", m._id, m);
    });
    self.ready();
  });
```

The log messages look right and when Meteor restarts it prints all the messages from the DB related to the user where the recipient is replaced correctly with the phone number. However, on the client side when I try to run `Messages.findOne(msgId)` (with an id I verified exists by selecting it directly in mongo shell) I get `undefined` back and furthermore, running `Messages.find()` through developer tools in the browser returns `undefined` as well although I expected the messages that showed up in the logs to be available..
I feel that this is a basic use case but I am not able to make this work.. any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you subscribing to "myMessages" on the client side? Meteor.subscribe('myMessages');

Comment: @Poyi yes. and if I remove the `forEach` part and just return whatever comes back from `Messages.find()` then `Messages.findOne(msgId)` returns successfully and I can display the data correctly, except the `userId` shows up instead of his phone number..

Comment: seems like the forEach part is not being returned correctly so you're subscribing to an undefined collection. I am not too familiar with transform but I'd suggest you double check whether the new `m` is being returned in that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can transform a collection on the server side like this:"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344597/4023641

It worked for me.

Unfortunately, changes in users collection will not update reactively these custom fields.

Comment: This actually worked. Do you know why my original code doesn't work?