# Associate each model returned by a Meteor collection's subscription

Tags: mongodb, meteor, subscription

In a Meteor application I am currently working on, some collections may have multiple simultaneous subscriptions (i.e. one to fetch initially, another when searching more data, etc.) Naturally, I do not want to have the entire collection downloaded to the client, so I'm relying on [subscriptions manager](https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager) and a need-to-have approach.

The problem is that, once the data is fetched, the collection on the client contains the entire content of all subscriptions, and I am not sure how I can discern which data was fetch from what subscription (i.e. which data was fetched initially, and which was searched, etc.)

I have thought adding a subscription UID to each fetched data (an array, since some data can be fetched from multiple subscriptions), but this seems hacky and prone to cleanup hell.

Is there a solution to associate and identify which subscription fetched which data?

---

#### Update

So fare, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18097186/320700) seem to solve part of the problem, however this is not the kind of solution I find "clean".

```
// ctx being the Metheor.subscribe context (i.e. const ctx = this;)

function transform(doc) {
  if (searchKey) {
    doc._searchKey = searchKey;
  }
  return doc;
}

const cursor = InventoryItems.find(filter, options);
const observer = cursor.observe({
  added(doc) {
    ctx.added(InventoryItems._name, doc._id, transform(doc));
  },
  changed(newDoc, oldDoc) {
    ctx.changed(InventoryItems._name, newDoc._id, transform(newDoc));
  },
  removed(oldDoc) {
    ctx.removed(InventoryItems._name, oldDoc._id);
  }
});

ctx.onStop(() => {
  observer.stop();
});

return cursor;
```

Comment: Interesting question. I've never seen a need for this pattern. Why does it matter? Since different subscriptions can give you different keys in the same doc it would seem hacky to manage. I was thinking that transforms might help but probably not.

Comment: I'd rather not use transformations, but if I have no choice... I used to use transformation to normalize my data, but then I lost the reactivity of the data. I now rely on [publish composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) to manage the normalization. So, if I fetch (for example) a post, it will automatically fetch the associated users. Then, if I search for users, I get all the users searched, as well as the users associated with the posts... two subscriptions, one collection.

Comment: Why do you need to discern where the data comes from? Is the data still structured the same way with the same meaning? If not, may need to restructure something into it's own collection.

Comment: @TravisWhite I perhaps do not understand how others do it, or maybe Meteor's documentation is not clear enough... The app I'm working on is for internal use, and rely on reactivity; you modify something, other clients should be notified of it. Thus, I cannot count on denormalization on few instances. For example, an order that should increase some inventory items needs to know the status of each items, and if an item is added, the user will search the inventory (thus creating a new subscription of the search criteria) which will add to the singleton collection. Can't have two collections.

Comment: @YanickRochon I guess I just wanted to know the use-case to help understand the bigger picture. Why do you need to know if data was returned via subscription1 or subscription2? An up-to-date order is an up-to-date order regardless of which subscription returned it... or am I missing something?

Comment: How many simultaneous searches will each user perform? You can create a "virtual" collection that is client-only and manually publish to it if you only have a single such search at a time and wish to separate its data.

Comment: @MasterAM can you put that into an answer?

Comment: What you have added in your edit is pretty much close to the way it can be done, although I would publish to a different collection name instead of adding a `_searchKey`. Additionally, I would use `observeChanges` instead of `observe`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer describes a way to publish data to a client-only collection.

If you want to separate some of the data, you can publish it to a different collection:

```
//client

const TempCollection = new Meteor.Collection('temp', {defineMutationMethods: false});

Meteor.subscribe('temp.query', 'queryParams');
```

This defines a collection without setting mutation methods, so any changes done to it on the client are not sent to the server (as it would be pointless). Note that the collection name (`temp` in this case) should be used in the server publication.

```
// server
const ActualCollection = new Mongo.Collection('real_collection_name');

function publishForTarget(sub, cursor, targetName) {
    return Mongo.Collection._publishCursor(cursor, sub, targetName);
}

Meteor.publish('temp.query', function(/*params*/) {
    let query = {/*...*/};
    let targetName = 'temp'; // or get it from the client for dynamically-named client-side collections. 
    let cursor = ActualCollection.find(query);    
    publishForTarget(this, cursor, targetName);

    return this.ready();
});
```

This uses the undocumented [`Mongo.Collection._publishCursor`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/8142521610dcf0d06f8a19119567477395e03fd8/packages/mongo/collection.js#L343) method, which is also used by the standard publication when cursor(s) are returned.

Its implementation:

```
Mongo.Collection._publishCursor = function (cursor, sub, collection) {
  var observeHandle = cursor.observeChanges({
    added: function (id, fields) {
      sub.added(collection, id, fields);
    },
    changed: function (id, fields) {
      sub.changed(collection, id, fields);
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      sub.removed(collection, id);
    }
  });

  // We don't call sub.ready() here: it gets called in livedata_server, after
  // possibly calling _publishCursor on multiple returned cursors.

  // register stop callback (expects lambda w/ no args).
  sub.onStop(function () {observeHandle.stop();});

  // return the observeHandle in case it needs to be stopped early
  return observeHandle;
};
```

It observes changes to the cursor and calls subscription life-cycle methods (which translate to DDP mutation messages) when things change. We are replacing the real collection name by the `targetName` when using it.

It means that all of the results will be published to the `'temp'` collection on the client and will be separate from any other data that are queried normally and are published to `'real_collection_name'`.